# Starting rails. postgresql_adapter.rb FATAL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I am new in Ruby on Rails. 
I've installed Rails and everything was working fine. 
Then I changed database from SQLite to Postgre (because Heroku don't support it),did git push to Heroku.Everything was fine. 
But when I restarted my local repository,it showed me this(on local repo):

user~:$ **rails server**

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.13 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1215:in `initialize': FATAL:  role "roma" does not exist (PG::ConnectionBad)
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1215:in `new'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1215:in `connect'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:323:in `initialize'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:27:in `new'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:27:in `postgresql_connection'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:in `new_connection'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325:in `checkout_new_connection'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:247:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `loop'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `block in checkout'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:in `checkout'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:in `block in connection'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101:in `connection'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/railtie.rb:88:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
from /home/roma/Templates/first_app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/roma/Templates/first_app/config.ru:3:in `require'
from /home/roma/Templates/first_app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
from /home/roma/Templates/first_app/config.ru:in `new'
from /home/roma/Templates/first_app/config.ru:in `<main>'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/server.rb:250:in `start'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

What can be cause of that? 
Sorry for bad English.
In addition this is my database.yml file

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: my_database_development
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: my_database_development
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

 production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: my_database_development
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Comment: Heroku doesn't need or use your database.yml, but your local server does. You've got something wrong with your Postgres setup and/or login credentials, as defined in database.yml.

Comment: Is there any way to check correctness of me database setup?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your error, you need to make a the user `roma` for your rails server to use to connect to your database. You can do this by using `createuser` to make your user defined in your `database.yml`. You may need to first do:

```
sudo su - postgres
createuser -P -s -e {your_machine_username}
```

but only if `createuser` throws an error with a normal `createuser -P -s -e {user_defined_in_databaseyml}`.

Then you can exit that user (`exit` will drop `su`) and do:

`createuser -P -s -e {user_defined_in_databaseyml}`

Then you should be able to `rails s` just fine (make sure you `rake` your db related tasks first).